# iMessage to Android phones over WiFi

Tags: iphone

What free WiFi app can I download onto my iPhone 7 so I can text Android phones and call them using iMessage over WiFi with no cell phone service? For can someone tell me how to do be able to call and text Android phones using iMessage

Answer (score 3):

iMessage is Apple’s proprietary messaging service. There is no other cross-platform app that supports it. iMessage does not support **calling** as it is only a text messaging service. It provides its own peer-to-peer messaging that is available only to users of macOS, iOS (and by extension to watchOS). It also supports SMS for communication with non-Apple devices. Cellular calls can made using the iPhone’s phone app and calls to Macs and other iOS devices can be made with FaceTime app. iMessage is integrated with both, but does not do the actual **calling**.

If you have no cellular service, it is not possible to contact an Android device with iMessage, as it can only contact Android devices using SMS. (iMessage can text and call iOS devices with just Wi-Fi however).

You could choose other services that are available on both iOS and Android such as WhatsApp, Google Hangouts, or Google Allo. Generally, both devices must have the same app installed for communication between them.

Answer (score 3):

You could turn on Wi-Fi calling and then your phone will use Wi-Fi to send regular messages. This could be the solution if your problem is merely that you don’t have cellular service available.

Go to Settings -> Cellular -> Wi-Fi calling

This will require a carrier that has WiFi calling enabled such as AT&T or Verizon.